# Database Link to ATP/ADW

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle18c

I am having challenges in creating a database link from an ORACLE DBCS to an ORACLE ATP.

I am creating a database link from an ORACLE DBCS (PAAS) to an ORACLE ATP (Autonomous Transaction Processing) database.   I can't seem to get the proper connection set-up for this.  Anyone who has successfully been able to?

My connection to the ORACLE ATP with SQLDeveloper is a zipped Wallet.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK TARGET_DB 
CONNECT TO admin IDENTIFIED BY "Myp@ssword123!"
USING 
'(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
     (PROTOCOL=tcps)
     (HOST=99.99.99.99) 
     (PORT=1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA=
     (service_name=eoakbwd540pwkbi_myuseratp_high.atp.oraclecloud.com)))';
```

-- ip address and service names are fake

When I test the DB link using SQLDeveloper I get the `ORA-28788` error code.

Comment: At the ATP end it doen's support database link. Please check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/experienced-database-users.html#GUID-791E7112-07F7-46F0-BD81-777C8FAD83A0) limitations page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  However I am creating the DB link on the non-ATP database.  So technically the ATP database is the 'target database' of the DB Link.  :)

Comment: please note the db link limitation has now been lifted.

Comment: Thank you Sebas for this info.

Answer (score 0):

### 0. Setup

You start out with two instances:

- DBCS - in my case Enterprise Edition/12.2 with port 1521 opened in the [security lists](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Database/Tasks/connectingDB.htm)
- ATP Instance

[Download the wallet zip-file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/connect-download-wallet.html) from the ATP instance containing a `tnsnames.ora`, `sqlnet.ora` and some wallet files.

Then upload the unzipped files to your DBCS instance.

### 1. Wallet Configuration

On DBCS: Replace the `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` in the `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` folder with the ones from the zip file (might need to merge them if you have existing entries that are still needed).

Replace the `WALLET_LOCATION` in the `sqlnet.ora` file with the actual location of your wallet files (specifically the `cwallet.sso` and `ewallet.p12`). Make certain the permission are open for the oracle user.

### 2. Database Link

You have two options for the database link (that I know of). First get the service names (e.g. `randomatp_high`) from your `tnsnames.ora` file.

- Using the username/password of your ATP admin user in the database link connection command

  `create database link <DBLinkName> connect to ADMIN identified by "<ATPpassword>" using '<ATPServiceName>';`
- Create two users with the **same** username and the **same password** in DBCS and ATP, connect to DBCS as that user and then:

  `create database link <DBLinkName> using '<ATPServiceName>';`

You might need to use `alter session set global_names=false;` to help with ORA-02085 saying the database link is connected to a different DB.

### 3. Test

Test the database link with e.g.:
`select banner from v$version@<DBLinkName>;`

Comment: Thanks char for this!